# Quarkus Decorator for RedisClient

Tags: java, microservices, decorator, quarkus, redisclient

Hi we are using RedisClient to access/update data in Redis from our microservices. What i would like to do is add a decorator around RedisClient calls to add additional information around this call. These calls are not in separate methods to add an interceptor so i am looking to add a decorator. Is it possible to add a decorator with no implementation class as delegate? I tried doing this but then the decorator code doesn't get triggered. Any idea if and how to achieve this?

Thank you in advance

Comment: The best would be to decorate the low level redis client. Did you try this?

Comment: There must be a delegate, otherwise decorator makes no sense. The delegate here would be the Redis client that Quarkus provides, e.g. a `RedisDataSource`.

Comment: Yes i tried to decorate the low level RediClient but the calls to the RedisClient don't trigger the decorator. Not sure if this is because the actual invocation to RedisClient happens through a proxy

Comment: So we are hsing the RedisDataSource and the corresponding HashComments, ValueCommands implementations to retrieve the data. These are slightly different from RedisClient which is injected directly in that you get them from the RedisDataSource so wondering how to inject a wrapper around them.